# Query com NOT IN no mysql

Tags: query

Tenho 2 tabelas (funcionario e funcionario_situacao).
Preciso de trazer os funcionarios com suas devidas situações.

O grande x da questão é não trazer alguns funcionários que estão em algumas situações (exceção).

Tenho essa query, mas continua exibindo os códigos que eu não quero apareça.

Onde estou errando?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.funcionario_situacao, 
    b.funcionariosituacao_title AS title 
FROM (".DB_FUNCIONARIO." a 
JOIN ".DB_FUNCIONARIOSITUACAO." b ON a.funcionario_situacao = b.funcionariosituacao_id)
WHERE a.funcionario_situacao NOT IN (:excecao)
ORDER BY b.funcionariosituacao_title ASC", "excecao=1,2,3,4,5,14,15"
```

Comment: seria bom colocar a estrutura das tabelas, que ajuda na hora de visualizar seu problema

Answer (score 0):

Não vi grandes problemas na sua query, ela só não trouxe nome nem id do funcionário, e removi um parenteses no from/join que acredito não deveria estar ali. Verifique o resultado:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.funcionario_nome,
    a.funcionario_situacao, 
    b.funcionariosituacao_title AS title 
FROM DB_FUNCIONARIO a 
INNER JOIN DB_FUNCIONARIOSITUACAO b ON a.funcionario_situacao = b.funcionariosituacao_id
WHERE a.funcionario_situacao NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,14,15)
ORDER BY b.funcionariosituacao_title ASC
```